# Remove empty space of UILabel with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to create a UIView in a library project and use it in my application. I have added auto layout constraints as follows:
[image]
[image]

But it produces the following result:
[image]

The labels have numOfLines as 0 but still, empty labels are displaying empty space. 
I have only given the height of the white view in the center (56px)

**Edit:**
I am using the view from library as following:
[image]

Comment: why label have constraints from both  vwTextInput and vwTextViewInput ? it should have from only one thats the  first thing.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan These are 2 different views, only one of them is displayed at a time, I am hiding other with autolayout

Comment: are you changing the hieght or just using isHidden property ?

Comment: I am using isHidden property but that shouldn't impact the label's height, its height should be independent as it doesn't have any height.

Comment: are you using heightFor cell delegate method in your code ?

Comment: i am understanding

Comment: no I am not using any table, just displaying it on the view

Answer (score 1):

One solution with Storyboard, where `UILabel` heights are dynamic based on its's text,

[image: image1][image: image2][image: image3][image: image4][image: image5][image: image6]

Or,
you can try using `NSLayoutConstraint` for the UILabel hights, for the ones you want to hide when the value is not there for the label,

```
@IBOutlet weak var errorLabelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then,

```
if errorLabel.text.isEmpty {
    errorLabelHeight.isActive = true
    errorLabelHeight.constant = 0
} else {
    errorLabelHeight.active = false
    //works as usual
}
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: No, I can't, if I do it multiline for the label will not work. I need to show/hide the view but label will only appear when there is any text in there

Comment: errorLabelHeight should be enabled only if label text is empty

Comment: Hi @pankaj, I have updated the answer with storyboard & AutoLayout where the label heights are dynamic based on the content, hope it helps